# How to conditionally close html tag in Angular 2

Tags: angular, client-side-templating

In php there is possibility to conditionally close html tag.
Can we emulate something like that in angular 2?

For example

```
<p>
    Some lorem
<?php  if(someConditionTrue){ echo "</p>"}; ?>
```

Comment: HTML tags are supposed to be closed. Can you please explain why you'd like it not to be closed ?

Comment: I want to close it at some point of the ngFor when some condition is true,something similar to example i provided.
Thanks for correcting my post Pierre!

Comment: Then you should probably put the content of the paragraph in a variable and bind the variable to the 'p' tag.

Comment: So im having simple  array with some data and  my desired output is

<div class="row">
    <div>item1</div>
    <div>item2</div>
    <div>item3</div>
    <div>item4</div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div>item5</div>
    <div>item6</div>
    <div>item7</div>
   <div>item8</div>
</div>

On every four items in array i want to open row display four items and close it.

I did it  already by transforming array into multidimensional array and than using nested ngFor directive,but i was wondering if something simillar to php is possible .

Comment: That's not supported in Angular2.

Answer (score 3):

Even though it works, there is probably a better solution, see the note below.

The script of the component:

```
private items: string[] = ['test1','test2','test3','test4','test5','test6','test7','test8','test9'];
```

The HTML:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items; let i = index">
    <div class="row" *ngIf="i%4==0">
        <div *ngIf="items[i]">{{items[i]}}</div>
        <div *ngIf="items[i+1]">{{items[i+1]}}</div>
        <div *ngIf="items[i+2]">{{items[i+2]}}</div>
        <div *ngIf="items[i+3]">{{items[i+3]}}</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/RDZFJFEZtTD0NA5d8YNJ?p=preview

NB: It would probably be better to create an array (rows) of array (items) instead of using the 'template only' solution I posted.

Answer (score 1):

This is a common frustration for developers with PHP experience, not a rejection of Angular or any other framework (such as Ionic). Unfortunately, you CANNOT put `*ngIf` conditions on closing HTML tags, and when you put the condition on the opening `<div>`, you will conditionally exclude everything INSIDE of the `<div>` as well--not just the tag you are targeting.

So, in the end, your code will be fairly redundant but you can solve the problem like this:

```
<div class="iterable-container">
 <div *ngFor="let item of items; let i = index">
  <div class="iterable-col-1" *ngIf="(i+3) % 3 == 0">
   <p>first column: {{item.name}}</p>
  </div>
  <div class="iterable-col-2" *ngIf="(i+3) % 3 == 1">
   <p>second column: {{item.name}}</p>  
  </div>
  <div class="iterable-col-3" *ngIf="(i+3) % 3 == 2">
   <p>third column: {{item.name}}</p>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

You'll also need some CSS. Here is some starter:

```
.iterable-container {
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
}

.iterable-col-1 {
  display: flex;
  height: 175px;
}

.iterable-col-2 {
  display: flex;
  height: 0;
  left: 33%;
  position: relative;
  top: -175px;
}

.iterable-col-3 {
  display: flex;
  height: 0;
  left: 66%;
  position: relative;
  top: -175px;
}
```

It may also be worthwhile to consider ditching those `<div>` tags for a good old-fashioned HTML `<table>`. She may be out-of-vogue but I feel like she was almost built for this.

Comment: My previous example assumes you need _different_ content for each of the columns (represented by "first", "second", "third", but it could be anything).

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue when I tried to display data on 3 columns in a responsive way.
The data that I had to display in the 3 columns was boxes with different heights (actually they were mat-expansion-panel).
I've tried first to use the flex from Angular, but that was not ok as I had spaces between the boxes (on the bottom and top).
I finally discovered a layout that was working fine by using bootstrap from Angular.
I had a dynamic number of boxes that had to be displayed in 3 columns.
In the end it should looked more or less like this (example for 9 boxes).

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row justify-content-start">
        <div class="col-12 col-lg-4">
            <box1></box1>
            <box1></box1>
            <box1></box1>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-lg-4">
            <box1></box1>
            <box1></box1>
            <box1></box1>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-lg-4">
            <box1></box1>
            <box1></box1>
            <box1></box1>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My first idea was to put a ngFor on the <div class="row in order to loop through all the boxes but the issue was ... how do I make the  <div class="col-12 col-lg-4 to appear every 3 boxes?
I used some help from this post, looking for a solution for an entire day on google and I did not found any solution.
Finally I come with the following solution and works fine for any number of boxes.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row justify-content-start">
        <div class="col-12 col-lg-4">
            <ng-container *ngFor="let cat of categoryProducts; let i = index">
                <box1 *ngIf="i%4 == 0">{{cat.name}}</box1>
            <ng-container
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-lg-4">
            <ng-container *ngFor="let cat of categoryProducts; let i = index">
                <box1 *ngIf="i%4 == 1">{{cat.name}}</box1>
            <ng-container
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-lg-4">
            <ng-container *ngFor="let cat of categoryProducts; let i = index">
                <box1 *ngIf="i%4 == 2">{{cat.name}}</box1>
            <ng-container
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The explanation is this.
Example: Suppose we have an array of categoryProducts. These will have the following indexes [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8].
As you see, the solution will cycle 3 times on the same array (is a little redundant but it's ok).
At first loop we will take in consideration only the elements with these indexes: 0, 3, 6. The others will be ignored but will be taken in consideration on the next 2 loops.
At second loop we will take in consideration only the elements with these indexes: 1, 4, 7. The others will be ignored.
At third loop we will take in consideration only the elements with these indexes: 2, 5, 8. The others will be ignored but already displayed in the other loops.
box1 can be every element you need: a div, a mat-expansion-panel, a component, etc.
The example had 3 columns but you can use it for any number of columns. In my case I needed 4.
This works fine for any number of boxes. All of them will be splitted into 3 columns.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you need this?  It seems like you're working against the framework instead of embracing it.

There are several ways to do similar things,  like ng-if, ng-repeat and ng-show.

A way would be:

```
<p>
   <span ng-show='condition' ng-repeat='item in collection'>
       {{item.Text}}
   </span>
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

My previous answer assumes you need *different* content for each of the columns (represented by the text, "first", "second", "third").

**Simon Aronsson** is correct that this is working against the framework. If you just need rows and columns of consistently-styled content you can simplify as follows:

```
<div class="iterable-container">
   <div *ngFor="let item of items">
     <div class="iterable-col of-3">
       <p>{{item.name}}</p>
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I use `.of-2` and `.of-3` classes to apply similar architecture to 2-col and 3-col views. Some starter Sass:

```
// assumes you have a color map:
.iterable-container { 
  background-color: color($colors, light); 
}
.iterable-col {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  clear: right;
}
// first column
.iterable-col {
  &.of-2:nth-of-type(2n+1){
    width: 50%;
    max-height: 300px; // depending on size of your card
  }
  &.of-3:nth-of-type(3n+1){
    width: 33.33%;
  }
}
// 2nd of 3 columns
.iterable-col.of-3:nth-of-type(3n+2){
  width: 33.33%;
}
// last column
.iterable-col{
  &.of-2:nth-of-type(2n){
    width: 50%;
    max-height: 300px;
  }
  &.of-3:nth-of-type(3n){
    width: 33.33%;
  }
}
```